# Changing the background color of selected label in a Switch

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there any way we can change the background color of the selected pill of the Switch in Oracle APEX 5.1.4.

Basically, instead of default switch appearing like this:

[image]

I want the Switch to appear as below, when 'Yes' is selected:

[image]

And appear as below, when 'No' is selected:

[image]

Is there any way to implement this?

Item's HTML Code:

```
<fieldset tabindex="-1" id="SHOW_RECORDS" class="apex-button-group apex-item-yes-no apex-item-select">
    <legend class="u-VisuallyHidden">&lt;b&gt;Show Data&lt;/b&gt;</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="SHOW_RECORDS" name="SHOW_RECORDS" value="Y" required="" aria-required="true">
        <label for="SHOW_RECORDS_Y" class="a-Button">Yes</label><input type="radio" id="SHOW_RECORDS_N" name="SHOW_RECORDS" value="N" checked="checked">
        <label for="SHOW_RECORDS_N" class="a-Button">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, found the way to do it.

I created a Custom CSS in theme roller.

```
/* Custom On/Off Color - No Color */
.t-Form-fieldContainer--radioButtonGroup .customOnOffColor.apex-item-radio input:checked + label,
.customOnOffColor.apex-button-group input:checked+label {
    background-color: #EF9A9A;
}

/* Custom On/Off Color - Yes Color */
.t-Form-fieldContainer--radioButtonGroup .customOnOffColor.apex-item-radio input[value=Y]:checked + label,
.customOnOffColor.apex-button-group input[value=Y]:checked+label {
    background-color:#A5D6A7
}
```

and then added class customOnOffColor in Advanced-->CSS Classes.

Thank you, Ivan and Tony for directing me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is it buttons group or radio? I don't have APEX 5.1, but assume you can write two css rules for this task. Something like this:

```css
.apex-item-option input[value='Y'][checked="checked"] + label {
    background-color: green;
}

.apex-item-option input[value='N'][checked="checked"] + label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Code listed above doesn't work. And it's a Switch item, which I believe is available in newer versions of APEX as well.

Comment: It's an example, you can try to create your own css rules - use "Inspect" function in browser  and create right selector. Post item's html code there if you need help in it.

Comment: Added HTML Code in the question. If you help me in creating the correct CSS Rules, I will really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: According to your comment to Tony's answer: can you show item's code when it has wrong background? It can helps to find the right selector.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
input[type="radio"][value="Y"][checked="checked"] + label.a-Button {
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff;
}
input[type="radio"][value="N"][checked="checked"] + label.a-Button {
        background-color: green;
        color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It works, but not completely. The default checked 'Y' background colour changed to red, but it didn't revert back to default upon un-checking the Y. Also, upon checking 'N', it's colour also doesn't change.

Comment: @AbhinavDhiman Maybe you need to use Javascript (or a dynamic action) to handle changes?  I can't test as 5.1 is a very old version I can't access.